# docker-compose network host is not working for macos M1 machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Environment:

```
- Docker Compose version v2.23.3
- Docker(podman) version:          
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.9.3
API Version:  4.9.3
Go Version:   go1.21.7
Git Commit:   8d2b55ddde1bc81f43d018dfc1ac027c06b26a7f
Built:        Tue Feb 13 14:55:17 2024
OS/Arch:      darwin/arm64

Server:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.9.0
API Version:  4.9.0
Go Version:   go1.21.6
Built:        Wed Jan 24 05:07:09 2024
OS/Arch:      linux/arm64

- OS: MacOS 14.3.1 (23D60)
- M1 chip
```

I have very simple service called `app`, which is supposed to keep listening to the message sent from the **`host`** network's port `1997`. The folder structure is like this:

```
 tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── received.txt
│   └── send.py
└── docker-compose.yaml
```

With `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Command to run the application
CMD sh -c 'pwd && ls && exec python app.py'
```

app.py:

```py
import socket

def write_to_file(message):
    with open("/app/received.txt", "a") as f:  # Use mode 'a' to append to the file
        f.write(message + "\n")  # Write the message followed by a newline

def start_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=1997):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen()
        print(f"Listening on {host}:{port}")
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print(f"Connected by {addr}")
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    message = data.decode('utf-8')
                    write_to_file(message)
                    if message.strip().lower() == "bye":
                        print("Received 'bye', shutting down the server.")
                        return  # Exit the function and terminate the server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

send.py:

```py
import socket
import sys

def send_message(host, port, message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
        # If you want to wait for a response, uncomment the next line
        # data = s.recv(1024)
    print(f"Message sent: {message}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])  # Join all arguments into a single message, separated by spaces
        send_message('localhost', 1997, message)
    else:
        print("Usage: python send_message.py <message>")
```

And most importantly, `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

So with the app up with `docker-compose up --build`, i would expect that i can run locally with `python3 ./app/send.py hello hello gello` and it will trigger the app service up from docker-compose to receive the message.

However, it seems such a pipeline failed because the container is not listening on the host's 1997 port:

```
python3 ./app/send.py hello hello gello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/~~~/draft/./app/send.py", line 15, in <module>
    send_message('localhost', 1997, message)
  File "/~~~/draft/./app/send.py", line 6, in send_message
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

If i run the same command **inside** the container, it would work:

```
docker exec -it draft-app-1  python /app/send.py jillo 
Message sent: jillo
```

So it seems that the `network: host` setting in `docker-compose.yaml` doesn't work at all.

I also tried the compose yaml with

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host networking silently doesn't work on Docker Desktop or other similar VM-based solutions.  On Docker Desktop, the "host" is a hidden Linux virtual machine, and not the physical host system.

For most practical applications you do not need host networking.  In the setup you show, the service listens only on a single TCP port, and this is typical of many applications.  Instead of host networking, a better approach is to use Compose's `ports:` option to publish that single port out to the host

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: ['1997:1997']
```

In the `ports:` line, the second port number must match the port the process inside the container is using.  The first port number is any available host port.  The two port numbers do not need to match.

On Docker Desktop, there is enough wiring automatically set up so that the published port will be accessible from the host system as `localhost`, as you show in your client program.